Having problem to install latest version of poppler tarball
I am currently using Kubuntu 22.04.
I want to install poppler which I need for using the yazi CLI file manager, but I have a problem working with tarball files and getting a build from them, I downloaded the poppler-24.06.1.tar.xz file and poppler-data-0.4.12.tar.gz from: https://poppler.freedesktop.org/
I tried:
tar -xf poppler-data-0.4.12.tar.gz
cd poppler-data-0.4.12
sudo make install
cd ..

after that:
tar -xf poppler-24.06.1.tar.xz
cd poppler-24.06.1

./configure

But when I get to the step that I need to enter:
./configure

This message occurs:
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

There is no such folder as 'configure'
I want to install poppler, but I don't know how.
Update:
I follow the instructions of basic installation inside the INSTALL:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..

then this error occurred:
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test GCC_HAS_AS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test GCC_HAS_AS_NEEDED - Success
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking _FILE_OFFSET_BITS for large files
-- Checking _FILE_OFFSET_BITS for large files - not needed
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:98 (message):
  

   No test data found in $testdatadir.
   You will not be able to run 'make test' successfully.

  

   The test data is not included in the source packages
   and is also not part of the main git repository. Instead,
   you can checkout the test data from its own git
   repository with:

  

     git clone git://git.freedesktop.org/git/poppler/test

  

   You should checkout the test data as a sibling of your
   poppler source folder or specify the location of your
   checkout with -DTESTDATADIR=/path/to/checkoutdir/test.
    


-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so (found suitable version "2.11.1", minimum required is "2.11") 
-- Found Fontconfig: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so (found suitable version "2.13.1", minimum required is "2.13") 
-- Checking for module 'nss>=3.68'
--   No package 'nss' found
-- Could NOT find NSS3 (missing: NSS3_LIBRARIES NSS3_CFLAGS) (Required is at least version "3.68")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:162 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find the 3.68 version of NSS3.  If you're not interested in the
  features it provides set the cmake ENABLE_NSS3 option to OFF
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:167 (find_soft_mandatory_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/glados/Downloads/Persepolis/Others/poppler-24.06.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


The .configure you mention failed because of the prior command, ie. you'd not used cd to put yourself into the correct directory; as the ./ in the command tells the command interpreter to find the configure script in the current directory.   You didn't actually state what you did, instead pasting a link to another question which provides many alternatives; thus is of no value to us unless you're specific as to which you followed & tell us exactly what you did (so we can compare with instructions if not obvious from output.. ie. your current problem relates to prior step)

The poppler maintainers appear to use the cmake build system in place of traditional autotools.
Follow the instructions in the INSTALL file located at the top level of the unpacked poppler-24.06.1 directory:

Basic Installation
==================

mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install


CMake configuration options can be set using the -D option. eg

  cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release


You will of course need to have installed all the build dependencies of the software that you are trying to install (or at least those for features that you wish to enable) - a good starting point is often to use sudo apt build-dep poppler however be aware that this installs the build dependencies for the version of poppler that is provided for your current system - which may be different from those of the version that you are trying to build.
